# $AX=C$: An Inconsistent Linear Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

### Question:

Let $A \in M_{n\times n}(F)$. Suppose that the system of linear equations $AX = B$
has more than one solution. Prove that there is a column $C \in F^n$ such that
the system of linear equations $AX = C$ is inconsistent.

---

### Attempt:

> ***Lemma:*** Let $AX=C$ be a system of linear equations. Then the system is consistent if and only if $\text{dim Im}~(A)=\text{dim Im}~(A \mid C)$.

Let $Y$ and $Y'$ be solutions to the system $AX=B$. Then

$$ A(Y) = A(Y')=B,$$

or

$$ A(Y)-A(Y')=A(Y-Y')=0,$$

so $\dim \text{Ker}~(A)\geq 1$, which means $\dim \text{Im}~(A)<n$, or simply that

$$\text{span}~(\{A^{(1)},\dots,A^{(n)}\})\neq F^n.$$

In other words, there exists at least one $A^{(i)}$ such that

$$A^{(i)}=k_1A^{(1)}+\cdots +k_{i-1}A^{(i-1)}+k_{i+1}A^{(i+1)}+\cdots + k_nA^{(n)}\neq ce_i,$$

for some $e_i\in \{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ the standard basis for $F^n$ with $c,k_i\in F$. Thus, by the lemma, we clearly see that such an $e_i$ is the desired $C$ for which $AX=C$ has no solutions, namely

$$\text{dim Im}~(A)\neq \text{dim Im}(A \mid e_i)=\text{dim Im}(A \mid C).$$

This is so because if $\text{dim Im}(A)=m$, then $\text{dim Im}~(A \mid e_i)=m+1$ for such an $e_i$ described above.

Acknowledgements: @jkn

Comment: The "$\mid$" denotes augmentation.

Comment: Am I correct that there is, in general, not just ONE such $C$ for most systems of this form?

Comment: Please don't make silly titles like that. The purpose of the title is to tell people reading the front page (or searching the site!) what this thread is about.

Comment: -_- OK... Fine...

Comment: @YACP I think that the questions are different, this one is an "iff" whereas the duplicate only asks for one implication.

Comment: @YACP Ah, sorry, I was looking at the "lemma" part, which seemed sufficiently different! You're right, this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The linear operator $A:V\to V$ is not injective. Therefore, since it acts on a finite-dimensional space $V$, it is not surjective. So there is a vector $C$, which is not contained in ${\rm Im} A$.